# adding dictionary data into a tupple in a python for loop

Tags: python, dictionary, django-models, tuples

I am struggling with this, quite new working with tuples and dictionaries. I am pulling data from my models and I want to get an array combination that looks like this;

```
{'Home': {'completed': '2', 'ongoing': '3'}, 'Lenan School': {'completed': '1', 'ongoing': '0'}, 'test site': {'completed': '1', 'ongoing': '3'}, 'Juala': {'completed': '0', 'ongoing': '0'}}
```

My code looks like this;

```
qua_sites = quarantine_sites.objects.all().order_by('site_name')
ongoing_cases = {}
completed_cases = []
combinded_array = myDict()
for qua_site in qua_sites:
    qua_completed_contacts = quarantine_contacts.objects.filter(quarantine_site_id = qua_site.id).filter(created_at__gte = date.today()- timedelta(days=14)).count()
    qua_ongoing_contacts = quarantine_contacts.objects.filter(quarantine_site_id = qua_site.id).filter(created_at__lte = date.today()- timedelta(days=14)).count()

    combinded_array.add('ongoing',str(qua_ongoing_contacts))
    combinded_array.add('completed',str(qua_completed_contacts))
    print("------")
    print(combinded_array)

    ongoing_cases[qua_site.site_name] = combinded_array
    print(ongoing_cases)
```

The combined_array keeps being overwritten by the last value. My print output is like this;

```
------
{'completed': '2', 'ongoing': '3'}
{'Home': {'completed': '2', 'ongoing': '3'}}
------
{'completed': '1', 'ongoing': '0'}
{'Home': {'completed': '1', 'ongoing': '0'}, 'Juala': {'completed': '1', 'ongoing': '0'}}
------
{'completed': '1', 'ongoing': '3'}
{'Home': {'completed': '1', 'ongoing': '3'}, 'Lenan School': {'completed': '1', 'ongoing': '3'}, 
'Juala': {'completed': '1', 'ongoing': '3'}}
------
{'completed': '0', 'ongoing': '0'}
{'Home': {'completed': '0', 'ongoing': '0'}, 'Lenan School': {'completed': '0', 'ongoing': '0'}, 
'test site': {'completed': '0', 'ongoing': '0'}, 'Juala': {'completed': '0', 'ongoing': '0'}}
```

How can I achieve the array combination that I want, like sample above. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you only have one `myDict` object, and you keep adding references of that same object to `ongoing_cases`, and then changing it.  This effectively changes the value of all entries in `ongoing_cases` (because they reference the same object).

To fix this, create a new object (`combinded_array = myDict()`) inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks so much shx2, this was as easy as i couldn't think of, we need a new object for every instance of the loop. I appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

Lists in Python are passed by reference, so all items in 'ongoing_cases' references to the same list instance, that's why the values were overwritten.

You should make a copy of 'combinded_array' in each iteration:

```
    ongoing_cases[qua_site.site_name] = combinded_array.copy()
```